# jstl url tag generates wrong url

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying to send the request to my Spring MVC controller mapping with this url:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/place/{placeId}/menu/service", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerNewPlaceMenuService(@Valid ServiceDTO serviceDTO,
                                          @PathVariable("placeId") long placeId,
                                          BindingResult result) {
    if(!result.hasErrors()) {
        PlaceUser user = userService.placeUser();
        Place place = placeService.getOwnerPlace(placeId, user);
        if (place != null) {
            PlaceMenu menu = dao.getMenuById(serviceDTO.getMenuId());
            if (place.getPlaceMenu().contains(menu)) {
                placeService.registerNewPlaceMenuService(menu, serviceDTO);
            }
        }
    }
    return "redirect:place/" + placeId;
}
```

This is how i use jstl url tag:

```
<c:url context="/" value='/place/${place.id}/menu/service'
var="newservice"/>
<sf:form modelAttribute="service" action="${newservice}" method="post">
```

And this is what i am getting:

```
http://localhost:8080/place/30/menu/place/30
```

I can`t even understand where did the last "/service" part have gone!
The page from which i am sending the request have this url

```
http://localhost:8080/place/30
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/place/{placeId}/menu/service", method =
 RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: thanx, this was a push in right direction, it seams i have some trobles with my beckend code not form url.

Comment: I think your return in your method has an error. Try to add both "menu" and "service" paths in order to make a concatenation and create the same url above in your @RequestMapping value.